# Mostrar mensaje "no hay resultados" en gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

Cómo puedo mostrar un mensaje para que al momento de realizar una búsqueda en un datagridview si no hay resultados se muestre el mensaje.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usa **[EmptyDataText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatatext(VS.80).aspx)**:

Ejemplo:

```
<asp:GridView ID="CustomersGridView" 
        runat="server"
        AutoGenerateColumns="true"
        DataSourceId="CustomersSqlDataSource" 
        EmptyDataText="No hay resultados.">        
        <EmptyDataRowStyle BackColor="LightBlue"
          ForeColor="Red"/>                
</asp:GridView>
```

Para aplicar estilos al mensaje de `No hay resultados`, revisa los enlaces que ha colocado el usuario SoftMolina en su [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/38444/78).

Comment: Muchas gracias me ayudó bastante.

Answer (score 1):

[GridView (Clase)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview(VS.80).aspx)

define el template de:

[EmptyDataRowStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.emptydatarowstyle(VS.80).aspx)

con este puedes especificar que se mostrara cuando no haya datos.